# Why Microsoft overload methods Console.Write() and Console.WriteLine() ? C#

Tags: c#

Why Microsoft overload methods Console.Write() and Console.WriteLine() ?  They can make method like this

```
public void WriteLine(Object ob)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ob.ToString());
}
public static void WriteLine(string value);
```

But they make It

```
    public static void WriteLine(bool value);

    public static void WriteLine(float value);

    public static void WriteLine(int value);

    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public static void WriteLine(uint value);

    public static void WriteLine(long value);

    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public static void WriteLine(ulong value);

    public static void WriteLine(object value);

    public static void WriteLine(string value);

    public static void WriteLine(double value);

    public static void WriteLine(decimal value);
```

Comment: Object means boxing/unboxing

Comment: But int,float,bool can't be big values

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Long story short, Microsoft did it for performance reasons.

An approach based on objects requires creating a throw-away wrapper object for every single call to Console with a value type object. Consider what happens when you call

```
Console.WriteLine(12345678);
```

First, `12345678` is boxed into an object. Then the object is passed to `WriteLine`. Next, `WriteLine` calls `ToString` on the object. Finally, the string is copied into the output.

At this point, the object from the boxing operation and the string from `ToString` become eligible for garbage collection. Microsoft decided that creating two garbage objects as part of each call is unacceptable for an operation so fundamental as writing to console, so they provided all the overloads that you listed.

Answer (score 1):

Without overloading you've to box your native types (int, bool, ...) to object. Boxing/unboxing is a useless perforrmance cost in this case.